# PERL Fixed Width to CSV based on Input Files

Tags: perl, csv

EDITED: I'm attempting to create a brief script that calls for an input fixed width file and a file with the start position and length of each attribute and then outputs the file as CSV instead of fixed width. I haven't messed with removing whitespace yet and am currently focusing on building the file reader portion.

Fixed:
My current issue is that this code returns data from the third row for $StartPosition and from the fourth row for $Length when they should both be first found on the first row of COMMA. I have no idea what is prompting this behavior.

Next issue: It only reads the first record in practice_data.txt I'm guessing it's something where I need to tell COMMA to go back to the beginning?

```
while (my $sourceLine = <SOURCE>) {
   $StartPosition = 0;
   $Length = 0;
   $Output = "";
   $NextRecord ="";
   while (my $commaLine = <COMMA>) {
       my $Comma = index($commaLine, ',');
       print "Comma location found at $Comma \n";
       $StartPosition = substr($commaLine, 0, $Comma);
       print "Start position is $StartPosition \n";
       $Comma = $Comma + 1
       $Length = substr($commaLine, $Comma);
       print "Length is $Length \n";
       $NextRecord = substr($sourceLine, $StartPosition, $Length);
       $Output = "$Output . ',' . $NextRecord";
       }
   print OUTPUT "$Output \n";
}
```

**practice_data.txt**

```
1234512345John      Doe       123 Mulberry Lane   Columbus  Ohio      43215Johnny         Jane      
5432154321Jason     McKinny   423 Thursday Lane   Columbus  Ohio      43212Jase           Jamie     
4321543212Mike      Jameson   289 Front Street    Cleveland Ohio      43623James          Sarah
```

Each record is 100 characters long.
**Definitions.txt:**

```
0,10
10,10
20,10
30,20
50,10
60,10
70,5
75,15
90,10
```

Comment: One thing that I did just think of is that code that returns the third row is the third usage of <COMMA> and the code that returns the fourth row is the fourth usage of <COMMA>. If I advance the row each time I use <COMMA>, what is a better format to go about this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you're slightly confused on how to read the contents of the COMMA filehandle.. Each time you read `<COMMA>`, you're reading another line from that file. Instead, read a line into a scalar like `my $line = <FH>` and use that instead:

```
while (my $source_line = <SOURCE>) {
    $StartPosition = 0;
    $Length = 0;
    $Output = "";
    $Input = $_;
    $NextRecord ="";
    while (my $comma_line = <COMMA>) {
        my $Comma = index($comma_line, ',');
        print "Comma location found at $Comma \n";
        $StartPosition = substr($comma_line, 0, $Comma);
        print "Start position is $StartPosition \n";
        $Length = substr($comma_line, $Comma);
        print "Length is $Length \n";
        $NextRecord = substr($Input, $StartPosition, $Length) + ',';
        $Output = "$Output$NextRecord";
    }

    print OUTPUT "$Output \n";
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you! New problem is that it only reads the first record in <SOURCE> for some reason. Does <SOURCE> read a newline character as a new record? I've got one record per line in the source file, is there an argument I need to call to tell <SOURCE> that?

Comment: The default record separator is whatever your platform uses as a linebreak.

Need more information about what SOURCE and COMMA are to know what to tell you.

Comment: I'm busy for the next couple days, but when I have time I'll try opening and closing COMMA in the while loop rather than outside it.

Comment: Opening and closing COMMA inside each loop successfully worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to provide enough information so that we can at least do some testing without having to read your code and imagine what the data must look like.

I suggest you use [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html), after first building a template from the file that holds the field specifications. Note that the `A` field specifier trims trailing spaces from the data.

It is all but essential to use the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) module to parse or generate well-formed CSV data. And I have used the `autodie` pragma to avoid having to explicitly check and report on the status of every I/O operation.

I have used this data

**my_source_data.txt**

```
12345678  ABCDE1234FGHIJK
```

**my_field_spec.txt**

```
0,8
10,5
15,4
19,6
```

And this program

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my @template;
open my $field_fh, '<', 'my_field_spec.txt';
while ( <$field_fh> ) {
  my (@info) = /\d+/g;
  die unless @info == 2;
  push @template, sprintf '@%dA%d', @info;
}

my $template = "@template";

open my $source_fh, '<', 'my_source_data.txt';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => $/ } );

while ( <$source_fh> ) {
  my @fields = unpack $template;
  $csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@fields);
}
```

**output**

```
12345678,ABCDE,1234,FGHIJK
```